# asp.net mvc rendering partial view on-demand

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I'm a newbie to asp.net mvc and I'd like to know if what I do is correct.

I want to create a view for searching people. Here's what I have so far:

- The business model class:

  ```
  public class Person
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    public List<Telephone> Telephones { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- The ViewModel class:

  ```
  public class SearchPersonViewModel
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string LicencePlate { get; set; }
    public string CarMake { get; set; }
    public string CarModel { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- The partial view :

  ```
  @model IEnumerable<MvcApplication2.Models.SearchPersonViewModel>

  @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
   @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Id)
   @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.FullName)              
  }
  ```
- The view from which the partial view is called:

  ```
  @Html.Action("Search", "Person");
  ```

*The controller method in the PersonController:

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Search()
    {
         List<SearchPersonViewModel> model = new List<SearchPersonViewModel>();
         model.Add(new SearchPersonViewModel() { FullName = "test", Id = 3 });

        return PartialView("_SearchPerson", model);
    }
```

Now the problem is that the Search method is called whenever the main View is loaded. What I want is to add a search textbox on the mainview for filtering the collection rendered in the partial view. How could I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an ajax request to /search and append the data to your page.

```
<div id = 'searchresult'>
@Html.Action("Search", "Person");
</div>
```

whenever your want to filter call something like $('#searchresult').load('/search?q=xxx');

Comment: but the action method will still be called when the view is loaded. I only want it to be called when he user hit a search button.  Also, what do you think of the way i've organised my code ? Is this proper architecture ?

Comment: remove this statement @Html.Action("Search", "Person");

Comment: yes you have orgnaised it well. Creating View Models for the views and partial views is a good approach to go with.

Answer (score 2):

This way your partial will render on click only

```
<script>

(function($){
   $('#btn').click(function(){
      $('#searchresult').load('@Url.Content("~/Person/Search")');

}
</script>
```

Comment: I've done it this way and now notice that I'm passing a parameter to the controller :  $("#divResult").load('/Person/Search', $("#txtSearch").val());   The problem I have now is that the parameter always come as null in the controller. However if I browse to the url /Person/Search/s  for instance, then the parameter comes as 's', which is correct. So what am I doing wrong this time in the javascript ?

Comment: I got it to work now:  $("#divResult").load('/Person/Search?criteria=' + $("#txtSearch").val());   I was not passing the correct name for the parameter....

Comment: nice. jquery to the rescue!

Answer (score 1):

You could use 2 ways:

- microsoft ajax helpers
- jquery

For both of them you need to remove `[ChildActionOnly]` and `@Html.Action("Search", "Person");`

Look at this example: [Using Ajax.BeginForm with ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410055/using-ajax-beginform-with-asp-net-mvc-3-razor)

Comment: why do I need to remove [ChildActionONly]  ?

Comment: @user1098555 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253769/using-childactiononly-in-mvc