# Prevent MVC Action called from outside the world

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Action Method of MVC:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult callAction(int Id, string ffs, string sid)
 {
     //Business Logic
     return View(); 
 }
```

and this action is getting called from the JS

```
 var _url = vpath + '/contraller/callAction' + sidpath + '?Id=' + id + '&ffs=' + bfSelected + '&s=' + fps;
 clickCount = 1;
 $.post(_url, function (data) {
     if (data.Completed) {
         location.href = data.ReturnUrl;
     }
 });
```

Now I want to prevent that action to be called from out side the world. This action should get called from the same application only.
I used that **[ChildActionOnly]**

**but its not work**

Comment: What did you write in the View?

Comment: Any type of HTML...Not any thing specfic

Comment: All your code shows is that you redirect in the success callback, so what on earth is the point of using ajax - just do a normal submit!

Comment: Are you sure it's not works? here is post with working example.Check again your code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253769/using-childactiononly-in-mvc

Comment: @StephenMuecke; My Code is just a example..the point is how can we archive to access it from outer world..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ControllerContext.IsChildAction property inside your action to determine if you want to redirect.

For example:

```
public ActionResult Index()   
{   
    if(!ControllerContext.IsChildAction)   
    {  
       //perform redirect here   
    }

    //do stuff here
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Its not working in my case..ControllerContext.IsChildAction is false when we call from the JS