# Where i need to authentication logic in my mvc project?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have a MVC application where i have used jquery for service calls and displaying in the views. I am planning to add call to authentication  in the layout page, but if user directly calls the partial view page, authentication will not call at all.

Comment: Why would a user call the Partial View? Are you using the User.Identity Model?

Comment: Nope. I am not using User.Identity Model. But i am not doing anything to prevent the user to call the partial views. I should be prevent user to call the partial views? I am new to MVC. Kindly help.

Comment: How are you making sure your user is Authenticated?

Comment: Passing the userid to a authentication REST service and ensure the user is a valid user.

Comment: And then? Are you not storing if the user is authenticated or are you issuing the request every time?

Comment: Check this out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: for example, if a user very first time go to the application via a partial view page, how my authentication will get trigger?

Answer (score 1):

I am not totally understanding what you are trying to do with the Layout file, but you can decorate your Action methods with `[ChildActionOnly]` to prevent the user from being able to navigate to them directly.  See:  [Using ChildActionOnly in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253769/using-childactiononly-in-mvc)