# Dynamic menu from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `Login page` where on login it takes user to  `Home Page` where `dynamic menu` is loaded.The problem is that when a user clicks on one of the `menulink` the `loaded menu` is not visible

This is because I have written the code inside `Index action` of the`Home controller`.

So my question is where should I write the `logic for dynamic menu` so that it is accessible on clicking the menulink.

**_Layout.cshtml file where menu is loaded**

```
 @model SMS.Models.ViewModel.DashboardVM

 @if (Model != null && Model.MenuParentList.Count > 0)
            {
                <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
                <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                    <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    @foreach (var parentItem in Model.MenuParentList)
                    {
                        <li class="treeview">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                                <span>@parentItem.MenuParentName</span>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="treeview-menu">
                                @Html.Partial("_MenuParent", Model.MenuList.Where(x => x.ParentID == parentItem.MenuParentID))
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    }                       

                </ul> 
            }
```

**Logic for dynamic menu goes here**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {


            var _dashboardVM = new DashboardVM
            {
                User = _employee.Users.FirstOrDefault(),

                MenuParentList=_db.Menus
                                 .Where(x => _parentList.Contains(x.Id))
                                 .Select(x => new SMS.Models.ViewModel.DashboardVM.MenuParent
                                 {
                                     MenuParentID = x.Id,
                                     MenuParentName = x.MenuName
                                 })
                                 .OrderBy(x=>x.MenuParentID)
                                 .ToList(),
                MenuList=_employee.Designation.Role.MenuRoles
                                              .Select(x=>x.Menu)
                                              .ToList()

            };
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a separate `[ChildActionOnly]` method that generates your menu and call it from the layout page so its available in all pages

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Menu()
{
  var model = new DashboardVM
  {
     ....
  }
  return PartialView("_Menu", model);
}
```

and create a `_Menu.cshtml` partial view to generate the html

```
@model DashboardVM
....
```

and then in your layout, remove `@model SMS.Models.ViewModel.DashboardVM` (a layout should not have a model unless that model is a base class for all models used by the layout) and then include

```
@Html.Action("Menu", yourControllerName)
```

which will call the `Menu` method and insert the partial view it returns into the layout.

Comment: Thanks mate for your wonderful support..I came know more about `ChildAction` from another `stack overflow question` [Using ChildActionOnly in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253769/using-childactiononly-in-mvc).Thanks `StackOverflow` for helping newbies like me. :)

Comment: @ksg, Can't help with that one. But IMHO, its a poor solution. If you must use Session, then you should always be checking on the server if the Session value exists, and if not, get it from the database again.

Comment: I agree with you on that concept , but what is the problem on extending session before it gets timedout . In the end it gives the user a good experience without having going to login page every time the session expires...

Comment: What do you mean _go to the login page_. You should not be using session for login/authentication information. That should be in the `FormsAuthentication` cookie.

Comment: Kindly look into [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909005/using-foolproof-requiredif-on-multiplecondition)