# Using Foolproof RequiredIf on multiplecondition

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation, foolproof-validation

I have a dropdownlist named CustomerType with the the following values

```
Id     Name
1      Student
2      Non-Employed
3      Employed
4      SelfEmployed
```

and I have one more property in my `viewmodel` `public string CompanyAddress{ get; set; }`

My goal is to make CompanyAddress required if dropdownlist has values `3 or 4`

I have tried the following but gets error `Cannon have duplicate RequiredIf`

```
    [RequiredIf("customerTypeID", 3, ErrorMessage = "Please enter company address")]
    [RequiredIf("customerTypeID", 4, ErrorMessage = "Please enter company address")]
    public string CompanyAddress { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 4):

This will put logic in your model (which is usually a no-no), but it will work. You could change your validation to be like this:

```
[RequiredIf("CompanyAddressRequired", true, ErrorMessage = "Please enter company address")]
```

And then have a property with a getter like this:

```
public bool CompanyAddressRequired
{
    get
    {
        return customerTypeID == 3 || customerTypeID == 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea how this might work on front end as well? Because it throws me an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value').  Exception occurred when checking element _ElementName_, check the 'requiredif' method."

Comment: Oh, gosh, I haven't used this sort of validation in the last five years. Hopefully someone else can help you. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

For the "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')" problem, add a hidden input element on your page for that new CompanyAddressRequired property.

```
<input type="hidden" id="CompanyAddressRequired"/>
```

I'm still working on getting the switchable field to provide validation summaries on my front end but this resolves the JS error.